# Why do tkinter buttons get pushed apart when they are under an Entry?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a calculator with Tkinter GUI. However, when I make buttons under an entry, they get pushed apart. Also, instead of the buttons being in their corresponding columns, they are way out of line. What is making this happen?

Code:

```
from tkinter import *

# Configure the window
gui = Tk()
gui.title("Calculator")
gui.geometry("400x500")

# Variables for displaying input and output
expression = StringVar()
input_ = ""

# Make the Entry
expression_entry = Entry(gui, textvariable=expression, 
width=49).grid(column=0, row=0)

# Make the Buttons
number_1 = Button(gui, width=3, height=2)
number_1.grid(column=0, row=1)
number_2 = Button(gui, width=3, height=2)
number_2.grid(column=1, row=1)



gui.mainloop()
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yGWn.png

Comment: The grid is enforcing the spacing. You placed `number_2` in the second column, meaning it will need to start after the end of the top row's first column (the text field)

Comment: @dsillman2000 assuming there isn't a duplicate of this question, that seems worth writing up as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because column 0 is very wide to hold the entry. By default, items are centered in their allocated space so the first button is centered under column 0, and the second is centered in column 1.

The solution is to decide how many columns you want under the entry widget, then have the entry widget span that many columns. Then, remove the `width` for the entry widget and use the `sticky` attribute so that it completely fills the space given to it rather than forcing it to be a specific width.

The following code adds a third column for more buttons

```
from tkinter import *

# Configure the window
gui = Tk()
gui.title("Calculator")
gui.geometry("400x500")

# Variables for displaying input and output
expression = StringVar()
input_ = ""

# Make the Entry
expression_entry = Entry(gui, textvariable=expression)

# Make the Buttons
number_1 = Button(gui, width=3, height=2)
number_2 = Button(gui, width=3, height=2)
number_3 = Button(gui, width=3, height=2)

# assuming there are three columns
expression_entry.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=3, sticky="ew")
number_1.grid(column=0, row=1)
number_2.grid(column=1, row=1)
number_3.grid(column=2, row=1)

gui.mainloop()
```

[image: screenshot]